# User Registration Form error message customisation

Tags: form, error-templates

Where can I edit the error messages for the user registration form e.g for

```
{% if account is defined %}
    {{ _self.errorList(account.getErrors('email')) }}
{% endif %}
```

I want to change this wording:

Email "tom.bowler@mailbox.net" has already been taken.

to something like:

Email "tom.bowler@mailbox.net" has already been taken. Login here instead...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using Craft's [static translation](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/static-translations) support.

For example, if your site is using `en_us` for its primary locale, then add a `craft/translations/en_us.php` file that has this in it:

```
<?php

return array(
    '{attribute} "{value}" has already been taken.' => '{attribute} "{value}" has already been taken. Login here instead.',
);
```

Comment: Works great. How would I get html to process in there though? Possible?

Comment: Yup... just add it.

Comment: Tried that, but I get raw html in the browser, also tried: {{ _self.errorList(account.getErrors('email'))|raw }} as well.